# How to dynamically arrange cards in a row?

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart, row

I want to put two cards in a row and have them dynamically resized based on phone size. As seen in the image, the right card has overflow error because the phone dimension is small. Looks fine on a bigger phone.

Ignore the first overflow error

[image: screenshot]

I have tried wrapping the container using Expanded() or Flexible() but it gives an error saying my parent is using a GestureDetector() and it does not allow that.

```
Widget _showSecondRow(){
    return new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
           new GestureDetector(
               child: Card(
                  elevation: 1,
                  semanticContainer: true,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
                      child: new Column(
                         children: <Widget>[
                                new Icon(Icons.drafts, size: 30.0, color: Colors.black),
                                new Text("Private\nMessages", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: widget.appModel.getPrimaryTextColor, fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),

               )
            ),
            new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                        new SubscribedScreen()
                        )),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 1.0,
                semanticContainer: true,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
                  child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Icon(Icons.star, size: 30.0, color: Colors.black),
                      new Text("Subscribed\nThreads", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),

                  )
            ),
       ],
   );
}
```

I expect both cards to be dynamically resized regardless of phone size and fit the width of the phone. Doesnt matter if there's gap in the middle.

Comment: Did you try to wrap each `GestureDetector` in `Expanded` or `Flexible`?

Comment: @Andrey Turkovsky I tried. It works!!! Thanks!! Can't believe I overthink it lol. It is a simple solution

Comment: Ok. Then you can accept my answer and question will be closed )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap each `GestureDetector` in `Expanded` or `Flexible`